# Displaying attribute values in IntraMaps Roam?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, intramaps-roam

I am having troubles with displaying attribute values in IntraMaps Roam. Let me give you more details:

- My QGIS project is based on an SQLite database
- The attribute table in QGIS is displaying the attribute value (which is text) and not the unique ID's (numbers) that belong to each possible value
- I created a form for one specific feature type and attribute, so it converts the unique ID's to the actual attribute values, because apparently IntraMaps Roam only displays the unique ID's linked to an attribute value. The form is also in the attachment as a screenshot.
- When importing in IntraMaps roam, and select a certain feature to check the attribute values, it only displays the unique ID's. For example (see screenshot in attachment) Dieptenauwkeurigheid: 1. This should be Dieptenauwkeurigheid: tot30cm. When I click on the 'edit' button in the information table, the text is appearing and it uses the unique ID's no more.

So, how come that the form stars working ONLY when you click on the edit button?  Why doesn't it display the attribute values in the information table?  Is this somekind of bug in the codelists?